# How to show Bar Navigation Menu Magento 2 Blank Theme

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation, topmenu

I'm new to Magento and currently working on setting up a version 2.0 shop.

However, I don't see to be able to activate/make the navigation menu bar to show in the Blank theme.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Late to the party here, and I think you've probably already figured it out by now, but you need to have categories UNDER the "Default Category". Then they should show.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I ended up using a version 1.9.x instead, so I’m not sure if these would have made it work or not. 
Sorry it’s taken me sooooo long to update this. @Matt McLennan

Answer (score 0):

Please add any category in admin panel and Navigation Menu will shown

Comment: Hmm. I think I did that. Here are two screenshots: https://goo.gl/photos/4mWzr2wqafCSUXBn8 Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Change "Default Category" to products and start your category tree from there.